# The SSL certificate provided could not be inserted

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I use google app engine trying to add ssl for custom domain. I use naked domain. After "PEM encoded X.509 public key certificate" and "Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key" uploaded. "The SSL certificate provided could not be inserted." is returned. I use https://www.sslchecker.com check private key/ssl match. It matches. What's wrong? I use key size "RSA 2048", nothing wrong ordering the concatenated certificates. Thank you.

Comment: This *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319559/google-app-engine-ssl-with-lets-encrypt-could-not-be-inserted

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time working with this error and found a solution for my problem here:

http://qiita.com/yogurito/items/550b50b262418e93da22

If I understand correctly, the key file needed to be without a password, so running:

```
openssl rsa -in appengine.key -out appengine-nopass.key
```

provided a key that GAE liked.