# Certificate parse error when upload new SSL certificates in AppEngine dash

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, lets-encrypt

When upload letsencrypt ssl certificate to the GAE project, (note: I did convert private key to RSA pem format), but the dash board show "Error - Could not parse certificate." error dialog box.

Looking under the hood, the console sends a POST request which comes back with a status 400 and the following JSON:

{"code":8,"errorSpace":"domains","status":400,"message":"8"}

What does this error mean?

Thank you

Comment: potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319559/google-app-engine-ssl-with-lets-encrypt-could-not-be-inserted

Comment: What format is your SSL cert in?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved this?