# How to setup SSL certificate on Google Cloud Platform without PEM encoded RSA private key

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, iis-8

I have bought SSL certificate and would like to install it on my website hosted on google cloud platform. I have successfully installed the certificate on my Microsoft IIS 8 server and when I visit https://example.com connection is secured. However, I suppose, I need to finish installing process according to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl).
This doc says I need to upload a new certificate on the page App Engine page. But it accepts only PEM encoded RSA private key. The seller of this certificate didn't provide this key in a proper file type and all my attempts to convert it via OpenSLL failed.
Is there another way to setup this certificate without difficult converting procedure?

Comment: potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319559/google-app-engine-ssl-with-lets-encrypt-could-not-be-inserted/38319855#38319855

Comment: what do you mean by `all my attempts to convert it via OpenSLL failed`?

Comment: Certificate seller sent me 2 files (with *.crt and *.p7b extension). But google cloud accepts only "Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key". Hence, I need to convert my current file with the private key to .pem extension

Comment: The key is the one you obtained when you generated the `.csr` file which you submitted to your certificate provider. You convert it with `openssl rsa -in <your_key_file> -text > <your_key_file>.pem`

Comment: Unfortunately, I got this error "Unable to load Private Key. Expecting any private key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the PEM and RSA key files required for the App Engine, do this:

- Export the certificate from the IIS server in a PFX format (eg. server.pfx)
- Transfer the file to a computer that has OpenSSL
- Execute: `openssl pkcs12 -in server.pfx -nokeys -out server.pem`
- Execute: `openssl pkcs12 -in server.pfx -nocerts -out server.key`
- Execute: `openssl rsa -in server.key -out server-no-password.key`

Use the server.pem and server-no-password.key in your App Engine

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Cornilescu mentioned `openssl rsa -in <your_key_file> -text > <your_key_file>.pem` is the way to convert request file. 
If u got an error "Unable to load Private Key. Expecting any private key" the way to fix it is to replace ">" for "-out"