# Pushing SocketClutser to Google K8S Engine, the Ingress service not working complaining SSL key is too large

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt

I have created a socketcluster nodejs app. I followed their official docs to deploy the service to Google K8s Engine. However the ingress service is not running up and complains about :

`Error:googleapi: Error 400: The SSL key is too large., sslCertificateKeyTooLarge`

I tried following certificates:

1. 4048 Key size certificate from Let'sEncrypt
2. 2048 Key size using cert created using Open SSL.

Both of them result the the same error.

Do any one know how do I resolve this? And where do I get proper certificate for enabling TLS?

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, only RSA-2048 and ECDSA P256 keys are supported:

`openssl genrsa -out PRIVATE_KEY_FILE 2048`

`openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out PRIVATE_KEY_FILE`

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled due to this error on using Letsencrypt certs with 4096bit private key to a GKE ingress - even creating the secret worked fine for [1].

Finally overcame with editing "/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini"

```
rsa-key-size = 2048
```

issued new certificate, keyfile and put those into secret.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl

Answer (score 0):

On **Cloud Shell**, **GCP** with **"openssl"** and **"gcloud"**, I tried to create **a self-managed SSL certificate** first running this command below to create **"myCert.crt"** and **"myKey.key"**:

```js
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out myCert.crt -keyout myKey.key
```

Then, ran this command below to create **the self-managed SSL certificate "mycert"** using **"myCert.crt"** and **"myKey.key"**:

```js
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create mycert --certificate=myCert.crt --private-key=myKey.key
```

But I got a similar error to yours:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) Could not fetch
> resource:
>
> - The SSL key is too large.

So I changed **"rsa:4096"** to **"rsa:2048"** then ran the first command again:

```js
                         // "4096" is changed to "2048" 
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out myCert.crt -keyout myKey.key
```

Then, ran the second command again:

```js
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create mycert --certificate=myCert.crt --private-key=myKey.key
```

Finally, I could create **the self-managed SSL certificate "mycert"**:

> Created
> [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject-923743/global/sslCertificates/mycert].
> NAME: mycert TYPE: SELF_MANAGED CREATION_TIMESTAMP:
> 2022-01-22T07:22:26.058-08:00 EXPIRE_TIME:
> 2023-01-22T07:22:08.000-08:00 MANAGED_STATUS: